# after loading a pretrained pytorch .pt model file: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, yolo, yolov7

I downloaded one of the pretrained yolo models from the link:
https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/releases

In this case, yolov7-tiny.pt is downloaded.
Then tried to run the code to load the model and convert it to onnx file:

```
import torch
import onnx

model = torch.load('./yolo_custom/yolov7-tiny.pt')
input_shape = (1, 3, 640, 640)
torch.onnx.export(model, torch.randn(input_shape), 'yolov7-tiny.onnx', opset_version=11)
```

An error occurs on

```
model = torch.load('./yolo_custom/yolov7-tiny.pt')
```

and the error message is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'
```

The issue is reproducible even on Colab. Is there anything wrong on the steps?

Comment: Please provide the full error backtrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the repository you linked, there is a zip file called *Source code* which contains */models* and some other helper modules. I was able to load the model in Colab by downloading the zip, expanding it to a directory in my Google Drive called *yolov7*, moving *yolov7-tiny.pt* to this directory and then running the following:

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import torch
import onnx
import sys

sys.path.append('/content/drive/My Drive/yolov7')
model = torch.load('/content/drive/My Drive/yolov7/yolov7-tiny.pt')
```

Comment: The model can be loaded successfully after following your comments. Thanks!